# Правильно ли оформление цитаты?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

«Да нельзя утерпеть, не писать: то луна прелестна, то закат солнца в роскошном Неаполе...», отмечал он в одном из своих писем.

Answer (score 2):

Автор вопроса, к сожалению, ошибся, цитируя отрывок из письма И. К. Айвазовского В. И. Григоровичу. Вот полное предложение:

**С тех пор, как я в Италии, написал до 20 картин с маленькими, да нельзя утерпеть, не писать: то луна прелестна, то закат солнца в роскошном Неаполе.**
[*Успех картин в Риме*](http://aivazovski.ru/?page=5282cf9c-330b-4e60-bd33-429e74e30e35&item=aae96c06-768d-4af2-b1f3-900f4316596d&type=page)

1. Цитата заканчивается точкой, поэтому после кавычек необходимы **запятая и тире.**
2. Если цитатой начинается новое предложение, то она [цитата] пишется **с большой буквы** независимо от того, полностью мы цитируем предложение или вырезаем его часть.
   ([**ПАС**](https://autogear.ru/market/books.php?post=id1=4&category=lunguistics&author=valgina-ns&book=2007&page=115): *Если цитата предшествует авторскому тексту, то после многоточия слово пишется с прописной буквы...*)

Правильное оформление цитаты будет таким:

***«...Да нельзя утерпеть, не писать: то луна прелестна, то закат солнца в роскошном Неаполе», — отмечал он в одном из своих писем.***

Comment: Почему у вас после троеточия стоит заглавная буква?

Comment: Если цитатой начинается новое предложение, то она пишется с большой буквы независимо от того, полностью мы цитируем предложение или вырезаем его часть. Разве не ТАК?

Comment: У Лопатина: "Если цитата предшествует авторскому тексту, то после многоточия слово пишется с прописной буквы; если же цитата идет после авторских слов, то после многоточия употребляется строчная буква".

Comment: Да, у вас все правильно. Если цитата предшествует авторскому тексту, то после многоточия слово пишется с прописной буквы; если же цитата идет после авторских слов, то после многоточия употребляется строчная буква: «...Книги Олеши полностью выражают его существо, будь то «Зависть», или «Три толстяка», или отточенные маленькие рассказы», — писал В. Лидин; В. Лидин писал: «...книги Олеши полностью выражают его существо, будь то «Зависть», или «Три толстяка», или отточенные маленькие рассказы». (Лопатин, § 142)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Артём-Артём! Ваши правки (как и бдительность) — ценны.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, нужно  тире после цитаты, т. к. цитата заканчивается многоточием.

> «Да нельзя утерпеть, не писать: то луна прелестна, то закат солнца в роскошном Неаполе...» —  отмечал он в одном из своих писем.

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139)